# How to show transaction logs message on frontend to user as alert message?

Tags: transactions, events, logs, console

I want to show condition in require as a message on frontend to user as alert message like 'wait for 5 minutes or wait while transaction is being processed'. In console.log, I can see this message but for user convinience, how to show it on frontend in react ?
**bold text is the message**

> Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit (error={"code":-32603,**"message":"execution reverted: Wait for 1 minutes"**,"data":{"originalError":{"code":3,"data":"0x08c379a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000125761697420666f722031206d696e757465730000000000000000000000000000","message":"execution reverted: Wait for 1 minutes"}}}, method="estimateGas", transaction={"from":"0x037182435bF0A591fc48fa0E58De19961A31eE64","to":"0xB0E9E0B6962B37022378B1C8aA24486BD8283B0A","data":"0x449d46c000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","accessList":null}, code=UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT, version=providers/5.5.0)

Answer (score 0):

If you place the code inside the try catch block, you can simply warn users by taking the error message.

For example,

```
try {
////Your code here.
}
catch(error) {
//When the above code throws error, catch will catch the error.
alert(error.reason); //OR
alert(error.message); //Try both and see which one suits you.
}
```

When the code throws errors, in your case, wait 1 minute, the catch will take the error. Then you are warning them by using inside **`window.alert`** or **`alert`**.

I used window.alert for example here, in your real app, either you can use modals or something else.

Tell me if it helps!